# Excel: Concatenate with date result has a number appended instead of date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that concatenates the values in two columns in Excel with some custom text.

My formula is:

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE_INVOICE_DATES @id = ", E2, ", @newDate = '",C2,"'")
```

but my output is a number for the date value. I was expecting my query to be

`UPDATE_INVOICE_DATES @id = 2495523, @newDate = '01/07/2008'`

but instead there is a 39454 number placed.

[image]

How can I concatenate so I get the date concatenated, not a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dates are stored as numbers in Excel, you should use [TEXT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) function:

`="UPDATE_INVOICE_DATES @id = "& E2 &", @newDate = '"& TEXT(C2,"mm/dd/yyyyy") &"'"`

note that `=CONCATENATE("string1", "string2")` is the same as `="string1" & "string2"`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, use this formula instead:

`=CONCATENATE("UPDATE_INVOICE_DATES @id = ",E2,", @newDate = '",Text(C2,"mm/dd/yyy"),"'")`

Or you can also try what simoco posted.